# Notification is not fully match parent

Tags: android, notifications

My notification is not fully match parent this is how it looks
[image]

this is how i'm creating my notification

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
                .setCustomContentView(remoteViews)
                .setContentIntent(
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        this,
                        0,
                        Intent(
                            this,
                            MainActivity::class.java
                        ).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK),
                        0
                    )
                )
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .build()
```

Comment: Can you post your `remoteViews` layout?

Answer (score 0):

that happens, because you are targetting Android 12. And since this version you can't create "real" customizable `Notification`, you have only [some area to occupy](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#custom-notifications)